# настроить Squid reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, squid

Пытаюсь настроить обратный прокси. Все делаю по найденным в интернете инструкциям.

Проблема в том, что не могу настроить так чтобы доступ к локальному серверу был с использованием домена 3 го уровня.

Что я делаю:

1. Создал локальный сервер ( алиас - **test** )
2. Настриваю маппинг - задаю шаблоны URL, при которых, в моем
   понимании, squid должен перебрасывать на локальный сервер.

Внешний домен, к примеру, **example.com**, следовательно я ввожу шаблон такого вида **http://test.example.com/**. Вот так не работает. Если изменить шаблона на **example.com** (убрать 3й уровень) то тогда все сработает. При вводе адреса попаду на свой локальный сервер.

Почему у меня не получается с доменом 3го уровня? Где я могу ошибаться?

Спасибо

Comment: А DNS на test.expamle.com выдает такой же ip-адрес как и на example.com ? И интересно зачем обратный прокси на таком монстре как сквид, nginx как то полегче будет

Comment: Спасибо. Ваш вопрос навел меня на правильное решение. 

Сквид потому что я использую роутер pfSense, там есть возможность установить пакет squid и везде в интернете именно так говорят делать.

Answer (score 1):

Решено. Дело было в настройках DNS. Вероятно нужно как то правильно делегировать моему роутеру, чтобы тот правильно обрабатывал доменные адреса 3го уровня.

Было так что имя http://test.example.com/ нигде не существовало и клиент не мог получить IP адресс имени.

На моем DNS хостинг вручную указал test.example.com - *мой IP*